# JSCH access to login putty

Tags: java

After successfully login into putty using jsch. I want to pass commands in string form directly from file and also enter should happen automatically.

If any one have idea please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An amazingly similar question was posed here last week or so. However, JSch has different channels, one of which is an Exec channel. Use it to send commands.

Comment: "login into putty" ??? PuTTY is client.You can't login into it.

Comment: I tried both exec and shell. But my requirement is not completed. But write now i got some hope to complete using my own code.

Comment: Not login into putty. I mean it login through putty.

Comment: InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("filelocation"));
            
            Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell"); 
            channel.setInputStream(in);